# Why does the following work fine in chrome webdriver but "is out of bounds of viewport" in firefox webdriver?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Scenario is moving to element by scrolling down automatically to the element and then clicking it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

(ActionChains(self.browser)
         .move_to_element(self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector(btn_selector))
         .click()
         .perform())
```

Comment: Is the element off screen in Firefox?

Comment: It's a Firefox issue . Firefox doesn't autoscroll like other browsers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException with Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777053/selenium-movetargetoutofboundsexception-with-firefox)