# ElementClickInterceptedException with EC.element_to_be_clickable using Chromedriver 88

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to download a file from the CDC website by clicking a button in a dropdown menu (I would just access the file URL directly, but the blob URL seems to change every time the download button is clicked when checking my download history on Chrome). This button can be found by clikcing the header "Data Table for Trends in Number of COVID-19 Vaccinations in the US" below the chart on https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#vaccination-trends.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

driver_path = "some_path"
vac_trend_url = "https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#vaccination-trends"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(vac_trend_url)
table_title_xpath = "/html/body/div[7]/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[1]/h4"
table_title = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, table_title_xpath)))
table_title.click()
download_button_xpath = "/html/body/div[7]/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/button/.."
download_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, download_button_xpath)))
download_button.click()
# ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
#    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, download_button_xpath)))).click().perform()
```

Although the first click to reveal the actual download button in the dropdown works, the second click to actually download the file does not.

```
Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (1445, 310)
```

The title explains my error running the code above. When I try to uncomment the ActionChain line, I get the [error described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777053/selenium-movetargetoutofboundsexception-with-firefox/52045231) despite using the very same method described in the post that should fix said error. The button does not seem to be overlayed with some other HTML element, so I am even more confused about what the issue is. Is there a workaround?

EDIT: I also tried [MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException problem with chromedriver version >74](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59819502/movetargetoutofboundsexception-problem-with-chromedriver-version-74) at another user's suggestion, still no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should simply download the file for you. By sending click to the element.

```
download_button_xpath = "/html/body/div[7]/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/button"
download_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, download_button_xpath)))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", download_button )
```